# Cordova sqliteplugin karma test description

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, karma-runner, angular-mock

Hello I want to implement some test cases for my ionic framework application which uses cordova sqliteplugin to get data from a sqlite database.

I'm very new in writing test cases for angularjs.

My goal is to test if there is data coming for my service.

Well in my app.js I open the database with this:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.services', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.config','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite, $ionicLoading) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    var dbName = 'testDB.db';
    if(window.cordova) {
      window.plugins.sqlDB.copy(dbName);
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB(dbName);
    }

    ....
```

My services.js are looking like this:

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['ngCordova'])

.factory('ProductService',function($cordovaSQLite){

    var getAllProducts = function() {
        var productList = [];

        var query = "SELECT c.name as name, c.id as id FROM cars as c ORDER BY c.name";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res) {

            if(res.rows.length > 0) {

                for(var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                    productList.push({id: res.rows.item(i).id, name: res.rows.item(i).name});
                }

            }
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });

        return productList;
    };

    return {
        getAllProducts: getAllProducts
    };

});
```

And my test description to test the service looks like this:

```
describe('ProductService unit tests', function () {
    var ProductService;

    beforeEach(module('starter.services'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('starter'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_ProductService_) {
        ProductService = _ProductService_;
    }));

    it('can get an instance', inject(function(ProductService) {
        expect(ProductService).toBeDefined();
    }));

    //THIS TEST FAILS
    it('should get some products from the database', inject(function(ProductService) {
        expect(ProductService.getAllProducts().length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    }));
});
```

If I run the test I get:

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'n.transaction')
```

I think its because the database is not really initialized during the test, so I tried to mock the starter app but it didn't solve the problem. I tried to google on this but could not find any examples or tutorials for karma with sqlite and angularjs.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Any update on this, I am struck on same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and it turned out the db was not initialized.
I ended up creating the factory for db to inject in the services you need

```
.factory('DB', function($cordovaSQLite) {
var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("my.db");
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cards (id integer primary key,question  text, answer text)");
  return db;
  })
```

Injecting in the controller :

```
.controller('CardsCtrl', function($scope, $http, $ionicSwipeCardDelegate,$cordovaSQLite,DB) {

   var query = "SELECT * FROM cards ";
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(DB, query,[]).then(function(res) {
  if(res.rows.length > 0) {
    ....do stuff...                                                           
 } else {

    }
    }, function (err) {
   console.error(err);
     });

    });
```